# Spring variable that begins with "@"

Tags: java, spring

I just started to use Spring, and following piece of bean definition puzzles me.

What does variable @{strategy.param.overrides.persist.file} mean and how do I find its definition?

Thank you!

```
<bean id="yyyyy"
    class="com.xxxxx.strategy.meta.MyAdmin">
    <property name="overridesPersister">
        <bean class="com.xxxxx.strategy.meta.AdminOverridesPersister"
              p:persistFile="@{strategy.param.overrides.persist.file}"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Hi the persistFile field is just a File type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bean reference, so it's referring to some bean named `strategy`.

It's mentioned in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in section 8.5.12.

**Update**: Ignore this answer. I can't get that syntax to work, so as @Augusto said, it might be something nuts going on with a prefix change in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or something else entirely.

Comment: In the example, it's directly `@foo`. Do the `{}` make any difference?

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing. :) It's definitely SpEL of some kind, but that's the only reference I could find. I'm guessing `#` should work just the same if so.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion that Spring is starting to cause with all the fancy configuration elements they are adding lately, if you define a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), you can change the **prefix** to `@{` and that will only do a variable replacement.

Comment: Good to know. That's a bit nuts. Are people turning their XML files into Velocity templates or something?